# What is wrong with my switch statement here?

Tags: javascript

Trying to output how a user inputted number compares to the number 117, very simple, yet I somehow am doing something wrong?

```js
let output = "";
//
//input Number here
let userNumber = 117;

function calcUserNumberFunc(indvNumber) {
    switch (indvNumber) {
        case userNumber === 117:
            return `the number ${userNumber} is equal to 117.`;
        case userNumber > 117:
            return `the number ${userNumber} is greater than 117.`;
        case userNumber < 117:
            return `the number ${userNumber} is less than 117.`;
        default:
            return `Invalid, or not whole number.`;
    }
}
output += calcUserNumberFunc();
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: `calcUserNumberFunc` accepts a parameter that you're then testing, but you aren't passing it any parameters. You also need to have `case`s that are *what you need to compare against*, like `case 117` - better to drop the `switch` entirely and use `if`s instead

Comment: You should not be using switch, use if statements

Comment: You can make the switch work with `switch (true) {`, but it is not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

While your code is syntactically correct (ie. doesn't throw any errors), you are not using `[switch][1]` the way it's intended.

`switch (expression) { ... }` evaluates `expression` and matches its values with the value you provide in the cases. In your code, you are not doing anything with that parameter.

What's actually happening, is that you are comparing `indvNumber` against the results of your comparisons (eg. userNumber === 117) and since all of them are bools (`true` or `false`) you are basically comparing `indvNumber` against true or false.

That said. For your use case, you actually what to use `[IFs][2]` statements to compare all your cases.

Also, when you are calling the function `calcUserNumberFunc()` you are not passing any parameter so indvNumber is undefined which evaluates to false (as is a [falsy value][3]) that's why in your code you will always be getting `the number ${userNumber} is greater than 117.`;. `userNumber > 117` is false and is compared against `indvNumber` which is undefined.

[3]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code to this and it will help to make the function more reusable.

```
//input Number here
let inputNumber = 117

// Assuming userNumber is the input Number and indvNumber is the number to be compare
function calcUserNumberFunc(userNumber, indvNumber = 117) {
  if (userNumber === indvNumber) {
      return `the number ${userNumber} is equal to ${indvNumber}.`;
  }
  if (userNumber > indvNumber) {
      return `the number ${userNumber} is greater than ${indvNumber}.`;
  }
  if (userNumber < indvNumber) {
      return `the number ${userNumber} is less than ${indvNumber}.`;
  }
  return `Invalid, or not whole number.`;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = calcUserNumberFun(inputNumber);
```

You can now pass input Number directly as userNumber parameter
Eg: `calcUserNumberFunc(116)` and it will return `the number 116 is less than 117.`.

You can also overwrite 117 to different number if you ever need to change it for example comparing user input to 120 instead.
Eg: `calcUserNumberFunc(120, 120)`. This should return `the number 120 is equal to 120.`